# How can I determine if every line in a certain file is the same?

Tags: linux, bash

I have one files:

```
$ cat myFile
fang
fang
fung
fang
```

How can I quickly determine if every line in a certain file is the same using bash? I hope I can find the different line number, for example, when apply to `myFile`, I hope the output can be 3(the line number).

Comment: You need to clarify your question. Do you want to see if one line is different between two arbitrary files? It's not clear enough. It sounds like you might want the "diff" command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$uniq -u file1

$uniq -u file2
fung

$grep -n $(uniq -u file2) file2
3:fung
```

Comment: Note: Works great if odd line out is unique. Won't print anything for `fang fang fung fung`.

Comment: How to solve this problem if the file is `fang fang fang fung fung`?

Comment: What output would you expect?  You can use `sort file1 | uniq -c` to display each different line in the file, along with a count of the number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
    line=1
    read a
    while read b; do
        ((line++))
        if [[ $b != $a ]]; then
            echo $line
            break
        fi
    done
} < file2
```

Pro: Will match `fung` for `fang fang fung fung`.
Con: Won't match `fang` for `fang fung fung fung`.

Comment: Breaks for fang fung fung fung, assuming "fang" is the mismatch.